# Android layout in java code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i'm making an app that requires indefinite textviews and images. i'm trying to implement a Pulse News app UI but having a hard time implementing one. so i thought of an idea to make a UI like that with the use of textviews, imageview and horizontal scroll view.
textview  string values are from parsed xml online and images or the imageviews will be images from a specific directory in the sdcard that my app is using.

can anyone give me ideas how can i do it without using an xml layout or is there any or other options or ways for doing this? thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a viewgroup with one textview and an image. Then it can be added dynamically to your layout many times. This can be done by creating objects in a loop. You can change the content in each viewgroup at the time of inflation.

Comment: can you provide a link for example?

Comment: You can create an xml with one textview and image. Then you can inflate that into the layout you want. In the abouve example dynamicoption.xml is the view group. In this a viewgroup is added in each click

Comment: i found this link more useful: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

though i dont know what exactly how pulse new app looks like, but by going through your question (horizontal scroll view in particular) I guess you want to implement a "Gallery" type implementation where in you can swipe left/right on page basis.

If my assumption is correct then you will like to see to [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) of android backward compatiblity pkg.

Comment: i also came up with that idea too, and found JakeWharton's ViewPager cool but i'm using GreenDroid library for my UI now, still looking for other options, thanks.